# Formula syntax (Counting unique values with conditionals)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got this formula

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(
FILTER($B$2:$B$10,
(($C$2:$C$10<DATEVALUE("1/5/2021"))*
($C$2:$C$10>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2021"))*
($A$2:$A$10=$F2)))))
```

and I want to modify it so I can use it with my own workbook references, but I keep getting a syntax error and I can't see where this is happening.

This is the formula I'm trying to create

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(
FILTER(MachineData!B:B,
((MachineData!C:C,">="&$Q$15-30)*
(MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&$Q$15+0.999988)*
(MachineData!N:N= $S$108)))))
```

Note: &$Q$15 has the date I'm referencing and I'm just trying to use the past month as my reference for the date ranges.

Comment: First ensure you have `EXCEL-365` to use Filter & Unique formulas. There will no comma in `include` part of filter formula. `MachineData!C:C,">="&$Q$15-30` this would be `MachineData!C:C>=$Q$15-30` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment try below formula-

```
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(MachineData!B:B,((MachineData!C:C>=$Q$15-30)*(MachineData!$C:$C<=$Q$15+0.999988)*(MachineData!N:N=$S$108)))))
```